# Python Calculator and understanding input errors:

Tags: python

I've created a small calculator in python which picks up input errors,  although it only runs once.
I was wondering is there a better way of doing this using While loop or If-else statements rather than using try-catch all the time.  As try-except should only be used in exceptional circumstances -

1. What I want is when user inputs an incorrect number, i.e. a string.  It errors out and asks again,
   the user inputs again the correct number and it works.  But using a while loop or If-statement instead of try-except
2. The below program works fine although it only runs once,  can you make it continously loop after it finishes.  I can add the other operators in later...

Thanks,

```
answer = True

while answer:
    try:
        num1 = int(input ("Enter first number: "))
        break
    except:
        pass
        print ("Please try again: ")

operator = input ("")
num2 = int (input ("Enter second number: "))

if (operator == '+'):
    print (num1 + num2)
answer = False
```

Comment: btw, I'm not sure you should ony use try/except in exceptional circumstances https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp

Comment: What's wrong with using `try/except`? That is the way to handle exceptions... I'm not sure I understand your question, if I enter a wrong value it asks me again. If you want the whole program to run again and again, just wrap it all in a `while True:`...

Comment: It's not a bad thing to use `try/except` for validating user input.

Comment: BTW, `exceptions` doesn't stand for "exceptional situations". They can be raised in regular situations, like `int(input(...))` for example.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Using `try/except` is correct**. Invalid user input is an "exceptional circumstance".

Your code already asks the user over and over for input until they provide a valid input (for the first number). This is correct. You don't need the `answer` variable, since it's not being used anyway. You can just use `while True`:

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = int(input ("Enter first number: "))
        break
    except:
        print ("Please try again: ") # You don't need 'pass'
```

You can do this for each input. Also, you can place that code inside a function (e.g. `read_number()`) and call it for both numeric inputs.

**2.** To make the program restart after it is over, **place the whole thing inside a `while True` loop**:

```
 while True:
    # Your program here
```

To make things more organized, you can put your calculator code inside a function, and call that function inside the `while True` loop:

```
def calculator():
    while True:
        try:
            num1 = int(input ("Enter first number: "))
            break
        except:
            print ("Please try again: ")

    operator = input ("")

    while True:
        try:
            num2 = int(input ("Enter second number: "))
            break
        except:
            print ("Please try again: ")

    if (operator == '+'):
        print (num1 + num2)


# main program
while True:
    calculator()
```

Comment: One more thing regarding the loop: Personally I prefer to use `while True:` and `break` instead of setting a "flag"... I believe it is somewhat more idiomatic

Comment: When I meant exceptional circumstances using try-except.  - It was because when user enters an input error,  this is not exceptional circumstance,  this is a normal circumstance, so could this be done easier using a while loop or and if-elif-else statement?

Comment: Could you send me the code for creating and putting it inside a new calculator() function, so I can add this to the program.  I'm still learning about functions

Comment: @BThind: Functions are very useful in organizing your code and avoiding repeating it. It's easy to do once you learn about them :) I'll update the answer with more code.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, the changes you gave me all work!

Comment: I'm just waiting for the extra information on def functions and how they can be used to make code easier and better.